# Where can be found globalOffsetX, globalOffsetY and zoom in class extending new JRGraphics2DExporter?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am upgrading libraries (from 3.x version to 6.0.0) in my project, which is using them, and I don't know, where get those 3 missing variables. They used to be protected in older version. Now they are private.

My old code:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPrintPage;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRGraphics2DExporter;

public class SRptGraphics2DExporter extends JRGraphics2DExporter {

    Double rotationAngle = 0.0;

    public SRptGraphics2DExporter() throws JRException {
        super();
        this.setParameter(SRptGraphics2DExporterParameter.ROTATION_ANGLE, new Double(0.0));
    }

    @Override
    public void exportReportToGraphics2D() throws JRException {
        boolean printPageBorders = (Boolean) parameters.get(SRptGraphics2DExporterParameter.PRINT_PAGE_BORDERS);
        rotationAngle = (Double) parameters.get(SRptGraphics2DExporterParameter.ROTATION_ANGLE);
        grx.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        grx.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
        grx.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);

        AffineTransform atrans = new AffineTransform();
        atrans.translate(globalOffsetX, globalOffsetY);
        atrans.rotate(rotationAngle);
        atrans.scale(zoom, zoom);

        AffineTransform sa = grx.getTransform();
        grx.transform(atrans);

        java.util.List pages = jasperPrint.getPages();
        if (pages != null) {
            Shape oldClipShape = grx.getClip();
            grx.clip(new Rectangle(0, 0, jasperPrint.getPageWidth(), jasperPrint.getPageHeight()));

            try {
                JRPrintPage page = (JRPrintPage) pages.get(startPageIndex);
                exportPage(page);
                if (printPageBorders) {
                    grx.drawRect(0, 0, jasperPrint.getPageWidth(), jasperPrint.getPageHeight());
                }
            } finally {
                grx.setClip(oldClipShape);
                grx.setTransform(sa);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: found it in old source code of JR (about 3.x.x version)

Comment: Protected -(zoom isn't in this version) http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/5.0.4/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRAbstractExporter.java#JRAbstractExporter.0globalOffsetX

Comment: I am trying to compile this code with new libraries...it worked with old ones and with new one netbeans tells me, the symbol can't be found - Should I send whole class?

Comment: If the class too big you can post methods with relevant code

Comment: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AjBJmuQjZfo4g-owM4cDkmBTsJfWXw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found inherited function `getCurrentItemConfiguration();`, where  I found these functions:
`getCurrentItemConfiguration().getZoomRatio();`, `getCurrentItemConfiguration().getOffsetX()` and `getCurrentItemConfiguration().getOffsetY()`.

So I've changed source code (with some other changes due other incompatibilities):

```
@Override
public void exportReportToGraphics2D(Graphics2D grx) throws JRException {

    Shape oldClipShape = grx.getClip();
    boolean printPageBorders = (Boolean) parameters.get(SRptGraphics2DExporterParameter.PRINT_PAGE_BORDERS);
    grx.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    //grx.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF);
    grx.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
    grx.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);

    rotationAngle = (Double) parameters.get(SRptGraphics2DExporterParameter.ROTATION_ANGLE);

    setCurrentExporterInputItem(exporterInput.getItems().get(0));

    ReportExportConfiguration configuration = getCurrentItemConfiguration();
    AffineTransform sa = grx.getTransform();

    float zoom = 1f;

    Float zoomRatio = getCurrentItemConfiguration().getZoomRatio();
    if (zoomRatio != null) {
        zoom = zoomRatio.floatValue();
        if (zoom <= 0) {
            throw new JRRuntimeException(
                    EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_KEY_INVALID_ZOOM_RATIO,
                    new Object[]{zoom}
            );
        }
    }

    AffineTransform atrans = new AffineTransform();
    atrans.translate(
            configuration.getOffsetX() == null ? 0 : configuration.getOffsetX(),
            configuration.getOffsetY() == null ? 0 : configuration.getOffsetY()
    );
    atrans.rotate(rotationAngle);

    atrans.scale(zoom, zoom);

    grx.transform(atrans);

    List<JRPrintPage> pages = jasperPrint.getPages();
    if (pages != null) {
        PageRange pageRange = getPageRange();
        int startPageIndex = (pageRange == null || pageRange.getStartPageIndex() == null) ? 0 : pageRange.getStartPageIndex();

        PrintPageFormat pageFormat = jasperPrint.getPageFormat(startPageIndex);

        grx.clip(new Rectangle(0, 0, pageFormat.getPageWidth(), pageFormat.getPageHeight()));
        atrans = grx.getTransform();
        try {                
            AffineTransform ertrans = new AffineTransform();
            ertrans.translate(
                    configuration.getOffsetX() == null ? 0 : -configuration.getOffsetX(),
                    configuration.getOffsetY() == null ? 0 : -configuration.getOffsetY()
            ); 
            grx.transform(ertrans);

            exportPage(grx, startPageIndex);

            grx.setTransform(atrans);

            if (printPageBorders) {
                grx.drawRect(1, 1, pageFormat.getPageWidth() -1, pageFormat.getPageHeight()-1);
            }


        } finally {

            grx.setTransform(sa);
            grx.setClip(oldClipShape);

        }
    }
}
```